# differences between mongo.linq vs c# linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb

Are there any differences between MongoDB.Linq vs C# Linq without Join mechanism? In my application, MongoDB is used as storage unit and Client Side Application has been coded via C# Linq Driver.

So, I want to store MongoDB query results to another collection and I want to let Client Side Application for querying Linq.

If there are big differences between C# and MongoDB Linq drivers, it will be big failure for both server and client side applications.

Comment: you can read it [here](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html)

Comment: @dotctor thanks. I've already read it but still there are some topics that not clear for me. Can I query with c# Linq on a Mongo collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not any `MongoDB.Linq`. There is `C# LINQ` and `C# MongoDB.Driver`. `LINQ` allows to write queries in C# then `MongoDB.Driver` translates `LINQ` queries to inner mongoDb commands.

You can face the problem that some `LINQ` constructions aren't supported by `MongoDB.Driver`, like predicate `Any`.